# Return Max Value Up to a Variable Date (Excel 2010)

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, max, match, min

How can the max value in a range be returned as a function of a variable date?

Here is a sample set of data:

```
ID        Date       Value
A001      06-Jan     0.90 
A001      13-Jan     0.95
A002      23-Jun     1.00
B001      02-Jun     0.90
C001      23-Jun     1.00
```

If a user wants to know what was the most recent value as of, say, 10th of February for A001, the value returned would be 0.95.

If a user wants to know what was the most recent value as of 30th of June for C001, 1.00 would be returned.

My attempt:

```
=INDEX(MAX(Entry[Value]),MATCH(UserSelectedDate,Entry[Date],1)))
```

Comment: Well... what are you seeing? Is it throwing an error? Is it returning 0.65 for the 10th of January?

Comment: Returns a #REF error.

Comment: Why are you looking for a max? Are you not just looking for the value associated with the last date prior to the user selected date?

Comment: True...so the max() piece has to be on the date side of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following array formula works for returning MAX/LARGE values under multiple/variable criteria:

For an example where the max value should be returned from a subset of dates:

```
={ MAX( Table[Values] * (VariableDate >= Table[Dates]) * (Table[Criteria1Range]=[Criteria1]))}
```

Formula structure:

Maximum Value ( Values * Boolean 1 * Boolean 2 * ... * Boolean N)

Answer (score 0):

So assuming Entry[Value] and Entry[Date] to be valid ranges and UserSelectedDate a valid named cell. Your formula is throwing a #REF! error because MAX returns a single value. Therefore when that single value is used as the lookup range in the index function, any MATCH function return greater than 1 will be an index greater than the size of your lookup range. If as we discussed all you want to do is get the value associated with the last date prior to the user selected date, use this:

```
=INDEX(Entry[Value],MATCH(UserSelectedDate,Entry[Date],1)))
```

If on the other hand you really need to get the maximum of all values before said date, you would want something to this effect:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("$G2:$G"&(MATCH(UserSelectedDate,$F$2:$F$5,1)+1)))
```

Comment: Can't seem to get either to work properly. I've appended my question to include a more direct example.

Comment: Using your first example, I tried:
        =INDEX(Entry[Value],MATCH([UserSelectedID&UserSelectedDate,Entry[ID]&(Entry[Date]+1),1))

(+1 to Entry[Date] added for inclusiveness of date).

From this, I keep getting 0.00.

Comment: Ok so let's make sure I follow... now the ID has to match in the lookup too?

Comment: Correct, I didn't mention this in the beginning as I'm comfortable with grabbing subsets of data based on multiple criteria such as ID. Grabbing the max value up to a variable date is what I am stuck on. The formula should be returning 0.95 when I have 16th of March (arbitrary date) specified.

Comment: And on your dates inclusivity... Which direction are they inclusive?? If everything in the ID column was A001 and we were just looking for date of 13th of January, what value would be returned??

Comment: 0.95, since the logic would return {0.90,0.95} for everything up to and including 13-Jan, and then grab the max, which would be 0.95.

Comment: The Match function doesn't return two items. In that case it will return the value 2 meaning a match was found in the second row in the range. Then we use the Index function to access the second item in the Value column which is 0.95. Also, MATCH with last parameter 1 will innately do greater than or equal to (no need for the +1).

Comment: `{=INDEX(Entry[Value],MATCH(IDChoice&DateChoice,Entry[ID]&Entry[Date],1))}` returns 0.00.

Comment: This worked:
`={ MAX( Table[Values] * (VariableDate >= Table[Dates]) * (Table[Criteria1Range]=[Criteria1]))}`. I will enter this as the answer in about 8 hours.